# Simple guide to TOR for beginners -- I mean really simple, and really beginner

Tags: relays

Is there a good, step by step guide for non-computer scientists on how to set up a relay or exit node while avoiding all the jargon?

PS I have an iMac that has an apache server, which I usually run through MAMP. Not familiar with command line instructions, but I can copy and paste with the best of them.

Answer (score 1):

So to kick this off, hosting a for relay/exit node use alot of bandwidth. When I say alot of bandwidth I mean I have heard of many reaching into the TB range monthly. Not alot of ISPs( internet service provider) support that kinda stuff happening on their Network. Tor has a list for you in order to find a good ISP [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/GoodBadISPs). If you don't want to do all hat you can host one with [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) and pay $5 for a nice droplet.

Instructions can be found with a quick Google search, Tor has alot of information for you to use also in it's [Documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en).

Running an exit node also will get the attention of companys, alot of the time you will get emails about copy right infringement and all that because people going through your node are doing that. It is recommended that you reply to them. All the information about legal issues and how to deal with a use emails can be found [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorExitGuidelines)